# How to add list of lists in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to add this list to a dictionary.

```
service_notes = ['Dog Timmy\n',
 'Breed Labrador\n',
 'Colour Black\n','Dog Bob\n',
 'Breed Poodle, 10, short, 2018\n',
 'Colour white,\n',
 'Dog Charlie\n',
 'Breed Sausagedog\n',
 'Colour Brown\n']
```

and want output as

```
[{'Dog': 'Timmy', 'Breed': 'Labrador', 'Colour': 'Black'}, 
 {'Dog': 'Bob', 'Breed': 'Poodle,', 'Colour': 'White,'}, 
 {'Dog': 'Charlie', 'Breed': 'Sausagedog', 'Colour': 'Brown'}]
```

I have tried many functions like converting this list to a string and then looking for words like "Dog", "Breed", "Colour" and then add the next word to a dictionary as that I want that information in the list but its not working. Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Comment: Your input is inconsistent. i see 10, short, 2018. Is it supposed to be like this?

Comment: yes, it is inconsistent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try...

```
service_notes = ['Dog Timmy\n',
 'Breed Labrador\n',
 'Colour Black\n','Dog Bob\n',
 'Breed Poodle, 10, short, 2018\n',
 'Colour white,\n',
 'Dog Charlie\n',
 'Breed Sausagedog\n',
 'Colour Brown\n']

res_list = []

i = 0
while i < len(service_notes):
    res_dict = {service_notes[i].split()[0]: service_notes[i].split()[1]}
    i = i + 1
    res_dict[service_notes[i].split()[0]] = service_notes[i].split()[1]
    i = i + 1
    res_dict[service_notes[i].split()[0]] = service_notes[i].split()[1]
    i = i + 1
    res_list.append(res_dict)

print(res_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'Dog': 'Timmy', 'Breed': 'Labrador', 'Colour': 'Black'}, {'Dog': 'Bob', 'Breed': 'Poodle,', 'Colour': 'white,'}, {'Dog': 'Charlie', 'Breed': 'Sausagedog', 'Colour': 'Brown'}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. Took me sometime to understand it though :-)

Comment: I tried to keep it as simple as possible. Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "service notes" are always presented in groups of 3 then:

```
service_notes = [
    "Dog Timmy\n",
    "Breed Labrador\n",
    "Colour Black\n",
    "Dog Bob\n",
    "Breed Poodle, 10, short, 2018\n",
    "Colour white,\n",
    "Dog Charlie\n",
    "Breed Sausagedog\n",
    "Colour Brown\n",
]

result = []
d = {}

for i, sn in enumerate(service_notes, 1):
    k, v, *_ = sn.split()
    d[k] = v.rstrip(",")
    if not i % 3:
        result.append(d)
        d = {}
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'Dog': 'Timmy', 'Breed': 'Labrador', 'Colour': 'Black'}, {'Dog': 'Bob', 'Breed': 'Poodle', 'Colour': 'white'}, {'Dog': 'Charlie', 'Breed': 'Sausagedog', 'Colour': 'Brown'}]
```

Comment: Brilliant, it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can try this :

```
from itertools import batched # Python 3.12
    
pairs = [sn.split()[:2] for sn in service_notes]

out = list(map(dict, batched(pairs, len(service_notes) // 3)))
```

Output :

```
print(out)

[{'Dog': 'Timmy', 'Breed': 'Labrador', 'Colour': 'Black'},
 {'Dog': 'Bob', 'Breed': 'Poodle,', 'Colour': 'white,'},
 {'Dog': 'Charlie', 'Breed': 'Sausagedog', 'Colour': 'Brown'}]
```